# How to add cglib to a OSGI manifest of RCP client?

Tags: maven, osgi, tycho, cglib

I want to use [cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib/wiki) in an [RCP](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Rich_Client_Platform) client. The RCP client is build using [maven](https://maven.apache.org/) and the [tycho plugin](https://eclipse.org/tycho/). We are useing a manifest first strategy.

This is my MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: INFO+ RCP Common UI Plug-in
Bundle-SymbolicName: a.company.prj.rcp.common.ui
Bundle-Version: 8.0.14.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: Schweizerische Bundesbahnen SBB
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-Activator: a.company.prj.rcp.common.ui.CommonUIPlugin
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Export-Package: 
 a.company.prj.rcp.common.ui,
 ...
 a.company.prj.rcp.common.ui.wizards.page
Import-Package: 
 org.apache.log4j;version="1.2.17"
Require-Bundle: 
 org.eclipse.ui;bundle-version="3.7.0",
 org.eclipse.ui.forms;bundle-version="3.5.101",
 com.ibm.ws.jpa.thinclient;bundle-version="8.0.6",
 ...
 a.company.prj.rcp.core;bundle-version="8.0.14",
 ...
```

To add cglib I changed the Import-Package section to:

```
Import-Package: 
 net.sf.cglib;version="3.2.0",
 org.apache.log4j;version="1.2.17"
```

Now Eclipse complains with:

```
No available bundle exports package 'net.sf.cglib'
```

Ayn ideas how to include cglib with this environment?

Comment: Well you need a cglib Bundle that provides this package in your environment. In Eclipse you usually do that with a custom target platform ( .target file, see for instance this [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html) ) that you can also reference in your Tycho build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the `cglib` bundle to your target platform, i.e., the set of all bundles Tycho will consider when resolving dependencies. You have three options to do so (taken from the [Tycho wiki page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform#Target_platform_configuration) on this topic):

1. You can simply [add an entire p2 repository to your target platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform#Simple_target_platform_configuration).
2. You can [use a `.target` file](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform#Target_files) and reference the `cglib` bundle therein (as already suggested by [stempler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982265/stempler)).
3. You can [declare a Maven `<dependency>`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform#.22POM_dependencies_consider.22) on `cglib` and make Tycho “consider” it.

As you already have a working Tycho build, I suggest you use whatever option you or your colleagues have used in the build before.

One more note: Options 1 and 2 require that the `cglib` bundle is available in a p2 repository, whereas option 3 works even if the bundle comes from a “normal” Maven repository like the [Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/). But in all three cases the `cglib` JAR **must** be a valid OSGi bundle, i.e., include an OSGi `MANIFEST.MF` with `Bundle-SymbolicName` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should build the `cglib jar` file to a plugin and install it in Eclipse before you can use it. You can refer to this link: [How can I add the external jar to the eclipse rcp application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227425/how-can-i-add-the-external-jar-to-the-eclipse-rcp-application/40581299#40581299)